# What would be the best way to search a txt file display all result on page in php

Tags: php, html

I have been trying to create a page where you can search a .txt file only using html and php.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$file = 'myfile.txt';
if (preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)) {
   echo "Found matches:\n";
   echo implode("\n", $matches[0]);
}
else {
  echo "No matches found";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this code. Your code is missing **$contents**

```
<?php
$file = 'somefile.txt';
$searchfor = 'search text would come here';

// get the file contents
$contents = file_get_contents($file);

// escape special characters in the query
$pattern = preg_quote($searchfor, '/');

// regular expression
$pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/m";

// search
if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)){
   echo "Found matches:\n";
   echo implode("\n", $matches[0]);
}
else{
   echo "No matches found";
}
```

Thanks
Amit

Comment: @JoeBoe make sure file is exists, the search text is present. same script is working in my local, i just tried.

Comment: Oh i forgot to change the values to my file name.